# passenger compilation error rake execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

we're trying to set up Passenger (the idea is set up as standalone). We installed it as a gem and when executed the passenger start command, we have found following error in compilation.

```
Compile the agent with optimizations?

Compiling the agent with optimizations will make Phusion Passenger faster, but
it will take longer to compile and it requires at least 2 GB of memory.
(You have 5.0 GB memory.)

Compile with optimizations? [y/n]: y

Compiling Phusion Passenger agent...
[**************************************************] |
*** ERROR: a Rake command failed. You can find the full log in /tmp/passenger-install-log-1qcyhcn                              . Below, you can find the last few lines of the command's output.
------------- Begin command output snippet -------------
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (2): [cd /tmp/passenger-install.vzccp7/libuv/&&...]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:57:in `sh'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:37:in `sh'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-5.0.14/build/common_library.rb:201:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

...
...

```
Tasks: TOP => /tmp/passenger-install.vzccp7/support-binaries/PassengerAgent => /tmp/passenger-ins                              tall.vzccp7/libuv/.libs/libuv.a
------------- End command output snippet -------------
The full log can be found in /tmp/passenger-install-log-1qcyhcn
```

Our environment:

- ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
- Rails 4.2.3
- Gem: passenger (5.0.14)

Could anybody help us, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post the full logs?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the delay. I uploaded the whole log here... http://www.wikiupload.com/T02YBJ6VTJDHERT

Comment: looking with more detail to the log file, it looks like is failing executing a "cd  command" in some structure that does not exist: 
** Execute /tmp/passenger-install.vzccp7/libuv/.libs/libuv.a
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (2): [cd /tmp/passenger-install.vzccp7/libuv/ &&...]
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:66:in `block in create_shell_runner'

Answer (score 0):

the problem was related to permissions. Re-executing the command with su, the compilation finished Ok.

Thanks to everybody for your support!

(We have to solve a new issue related to PCRE headers... :)